# Nginx route https as http

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx server which proxies requests to a service which works on https.
Nginx server is in the same private network with my services which use it.
Can I use http between my service and nginx or in this case nginx will not encrypt traffic between nginx and external service?
So I have:

MyService --*privite network http request*--> Nginx --*https*--> exteranl service.

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://example.com;
    }
}
```

My concern is that I send http request and expect encrypted data somewhere along the way.

Will it realy work as Nginx --*https*--> external  or it will be Nginx --*http*--> external?

Comment: What happened when you tried? If you tell Nginx to use https it will use https. It doesn't randomly defy your orders.

Comment: It returns correct value

Comment: If it is API based backend or HTML based?